# google maps direction service not permitting nested plain js call to elevation service

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a project whereby a route is generated by the google maps directions service, and I have a loop to obtain all coordinates along it (using a functioned called showPathInfo - see base of query for full HTML):

```
var tp = result.routes[0].legs[i].steps[j].path[k]; // local variable
var z = new google.maps.LatLng(tp.lat(),tp.lng());  // local variable
```

I wish to make a call to the elevation service during each loop iteration using:

```
elevation = getElevation(z);  // global variable but NOT an array
```

where getElevation is a function (see base of query for full HTML).

For some reason, even though the coords are correctly passed to the function, and are rendered appropriately into a getElevationForLocations object (I have checked this by having the getElevation return variables before the getElevationForLocations call); the service returns "undefined" for

```
return results[0].elevation;
```

I am interested in getting this solution to work to take advantage of the higher accuracy afforded to individual elevation service requests, and am trying to avoid batch requests with locations[] as a full array or using the getElevationForPath function.

Admittedly there is the problem of a limit to the number of single elevation requests that can be made per second and in total, but I have tried slowing down the code execution and limiting the distances in order to get this to work at least once:

```
function wait() { setTimeout(function () { 
elevation = getElevation(z); // here defined as a global variable
}, 500);}
wait();
```

Does anyone have any ideas why such a nested call like this cannot work?

The full fiddle html code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>html, body, #map-canvas {height: 100%;margin: 0px;padding: 0px}</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
<script>

var rendererOptions = { draggable: true };
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var map;
var elevation; // *******************
var elevator;

var start = new google.maps.LatLng(55.60289406109326, -2.88885779678822);
var wpnt1 = new google.maps.LatLng(55.59226543103951, -2.91247397661209);
var wpnt2 = new google.maps.LatLng(55.57330299699533, -2.88813963532448);
var wpnt3 = new google.maps.LatLng(55.58132161006218, -2.84357875585556);
var wpnt4 = new google.maps.LatLng(55.58602383263128, -2.87256672978401);
var wpnt5 = new google.maps.LatLng(55.60450928199337, -2.89154000580311);
var ended = new google.maps.LatLng(55.60289406109326, -2.88885779678822);

function initialize() {
elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService();
var mapOptions = { zoom: 10,center: start };

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directionsPanel'));

google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
document.getElementById('points').innerHTML = "";
showPathInfo(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
});

calcRoute();

} // ***** End of initialise function

function calcRoute() {

var request = {origin: start,destination: ended,
waypoints:[{location: wpnt1}, {location: wpnt2}, {location: wpnt3}, {location: wpnt4}, {location: wpnt5}],
travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
};
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
}
});
}

function showPathInfo(result) {
var total = 0;
var ns = 0;
var pt = 0;
var myroute = result.routes[0];
document.getElementById('points').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<th>Point</th><th>Lat</th><th>Lon</th><th>Elevation</th>');
for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
  total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
  ns    += myroute.legs[i].steps.length;
    for (var j = 0; j < myroute.legs[i].steps.length; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < myroute.legs[i].steps[j].path.length; k++) {

        var tp = myroute.legs[i].steps[j].path[k];
        var z = new google.maps.LatLng(tp.lat(),tp.lng());

        //function wait() { setTimeout(function () {

        elevation = getElevation(z);

        //}, 500);}  // End of getAndWait
        //wait();

        document.getElementById('points').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
        '<tr><td>' + pt + '</td><td>' +
        tp.lat().toFixed(7) + '</td><td>' +
        tp.lng().toFixed(7) + '</td><td>' +
        elevation + '</td></tr>');
        pt += 1;
        }
    }
}
total = total / 1000.0;
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + ' km';
document.getElementById('legs').innerHTML = myroute.legs.length;
document.getElementById('steps').innerHTML = ns;
}

function getElevation(z) {
var locations = [];
var clickedLocation = z;
locations.push(clickedLocation);
var positionalRequest = { 'locations': locations }

elevator.getElevationForLocations(positionalRequest, function(results, status) {

if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {

  // Retrieve the first result
  if (results[0]) {

    return results[0].elevation;

  } else {
    return 'No results found';
  }
} else {
  return 'Elevation service failed due to: ' + status;
}
});
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas" style="float:left;width:70%; height:100%"></div>
<div id="directionsPanel" style="float:right;width:30%;height 25%">
<p>Total Distance: <span id="total"></span> Legs: <span id="legs"></span>Steps: <span id="steps"></span></p>
<table id="points"></table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The elevations service is asynchronous, you can't return anything from the callback function, you need to _use_ it there.

Comment: Thanks - i have already tried that and it did not work - any other ideas?

Comment: Please show us the code where you tried that and it didn't work; it should.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the call:

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the call "elevation = getElevation(z);" from showPathInfo() would be eliminated, and substituted with "getElevation();" and getElevation would be amended so that "return results[0].elevation;"  becomes something like "elevation[x] = results[0].elevation;" were elevation is now a global array variable, and x is a global counter variable shared between both functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postscript

In the end it was the use of a Bluebird promise loop that worked.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/latest/bluebird.js"></script>
```

For the record I was not using node.js or any other functionality other than just plain js plus bluebird.  Promises are dealt with in detail by many answers in StackOverflow so I recommend reading these and looking through the API: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md .